# Is there syntactic sugar for a function that accepts a tuple?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function that takes two arguments and performs some calculation on them:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

I want to call this function through a multiprocessing library which can only handle functions with a single argument. So, I change the function to take its argument as a single tuple instead:

```
def add2(ab):
    a, b = ab
    return a + b
```

However, this seems clunky to me. The variables essentially need to be defined (and documented) twice. If I were using a lambda function, I could just write the following and it will accept the tuple properly:

```
add3 = lambda (a, b): a + b
```

Unfortunately, my function is not trivial enough to implement as a lambda function. Is there any sort of syntactic sugar feature in python that would allow me to write a named function that accepts a tuple but treats each component of that tuple as a separate named argument? My attempts to search for solutions to this have mostly turned up references to the `*args` operator, but that does not apply here because I do not control the site where the function is called.

Here is an example of how the function is being called. Note that it is called via the multiprocessing library so I cannot pass more than one argument:

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
for result in pool.imap_unordered(add, [(1,2),(3,4)]):
    print(result)
```

Answers for either python 2.7 or 3.x are welcome.

Comment: At the moment I'm using 2.7 but answers for either version would be helpful

Comment: The best way is to accept two parameters in the function definition, and use `*` to unpack the tuple when calling: `add(*items)`

Comment: you can convert your lambda to decorator and to decorate all such functions

Comment: @kindall I don't think that works for my situation, see edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best not to alter the original function interface, making it less Pythonic. 
 In Python 2, write a wrapper function to use with multiprocessing.

```
def _add(args):
    return add(*args)
```

In Python 3, just use `Pool.starmap` instead:

```
>>> def add(a, b):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> p = Pool()
>>> list(p.starmap(add, [(1, 2), ('hello', ' world')]))
[3, 'hello world']
```

Comment: Great idea.  It is good to note to `itertools.starmap` is available too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about repeating yourself (`a` and `b` appear too many times), simply give the incoming tuple a non-descriptive name.

```
def add(t):
    a, b = t
    return a + b
```

Or, in your specific case, you can avoid `a` and `b` altogether by indexing the tuple:

```
def add(addends):
    return addends[0] + addends[1]
```

As an alternative, you could wrap your function so the source code has the familiar argument format, but the function in use has the tuple argument:

```
def tupleize(func):
    def wrapper(tup):
        return func(*tup)
    return wrapper

@tupleize
def add(a, b):
    return a+b

t = 1, 2
assert(add(t) == 3)
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but it doesn't seem to work with multiprocessing. I tried it too, but it fails with `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'tupleize.<locals>.wrapper'`.

Answer (score -1):

As I was writing this question, I found the way to do it in Python 2.7:

```
def add4((a, b)):
    return a + b
```

However apparently this no longer works in Python 3, so additional answers regarding Python 3 would still be helpful.

Comment: ... which is the same way as to do it in a lambda, of course. This syntax is no longer supported in Python 3.x, however.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that, thanks. I'll update the question/answer

Answer (score -1):

You could use a decorator to extend the multiprocessing library function to take multiple arguments, do whatever you want to them, and then call it with a single argument.

For example, a simple decorator that takes any number of arguments, sums them together, then calls the original function with the total as a single argument:

```
import 3rdpartylib

def sum_args(func):
    def inner(*args):
      return func(sum(args))
    return inner

# Replace imported function with decorated version
3rdpartylib = sum_args(3rdpartylib)

# Decorate your own libraries
@sum_args
def my_own_lib(number):
    print("A:", number)

3rdpartylib(1,2,3,4)
my_own_lib(5,10,15)
```

The main advantage is that you can decorate/replace any number of methods with this same decorator function to achieve the same effect.